# FSharp.Data CsvProvider performance

Tags: f#, mono, f#-data

I have a csv file with 6 columns and 678,552 rows. Unfortunately I cannot share any data sample but the types are straightforward: `int64`, `int64`, `date`, `date`, `string`, `string` and there are no missing values.

Time to load this data in a dataframe in R using `read.table`: ~ 3 seconds.

Time to load this data using CsvFile.Load in F#: ~ 3 seconds.

Time to load this data in a Deedle dataframe in F#: ~ 7 seconds.

Adding `inferTypes=false`and providing a schema to Deedle's `Frame.ReadCsv` reduces the time to ~ 3 seconds

Time to load this data using CsvProvider in F#: **~ 5 minutes**.

And this 5 minutes is even after I define the types in the `Schema` parameter, presumably eliminating the time F# would use to infer them.

I understand that the type provider needs to do a lot more than R or CsvFile.Load in order to parse the data into the correct data type but I am surprised by the x100 speed penalty. Even more confusing is the time Deedle takes to load the data since it also needs to infer types and cast appropriately, organize in Series, etc. I would actually have expected Deedle to take longer than CsvProvider.

In [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730130/performance-issue-with-csv-typeprovider-from-fsharp-data) the bad performance of CsvProvider was caused by a large number of columns which is not my case.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if there is any way to speed things up a bit.

Just to clarify: creating the provider is almost instantaneous. It is when I force the generated sequence to be realized by `Seq.length df.Rows` that it takes ~ 5 minutes for the fsharpi prompt to return.

I'm on a linux system, F# v4.1 on mono v4.6.1.

Here is the code for the CsvProvider

```
let [<Literal>] SEP = "|"
let [<Literal>] CULTURE = "sv-SE"
let [<Literal>] DATAFILE = dataroot + "all_diagnoses.csv"

type DiagnosesProvider = CsvProvider<DATAFILE, Separators=SEP, Culture=CULTURE>
let diagnoses = DiagnosesProvider()
```

**EDIT1:** 
I added the time Deedle takes to load the data into a frame.

**EDIT2:**
Added the time Deedle takes if `inferTypes=false` and a schema is provided.

Also, supplying `CacheRows=false` in the CsvProvider as suggested in the comments has no perceptible effect in the time to load.

**EDIT3:**
Ok, we are getting somewhere. For some peculiar reason it seems that `Culture` is the culprit. If I omit this argument, CsvProvider loads the data in ~ 7 seconds. I am unsure what could be causing this. My system's locale is en_US. The data however come from an SQL Server in swedish locale where decimal digits are separated by ',' instead of '.'. This particular dataset does not have any decimals, so I can omit Culture altogether. Another set however has 2 decimal columns and more than 1,000,000 rows. My next task is to test this on a Windows system which I don't have available at the moment.

**EDIT4:**
Problem seems solved but I still don't understand what causes it. If I change the culture "globally" by doing:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo("sv-SE")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo("sv-SE")
```

and then remove the `Culture="sv-SE"` argument from the CsvProvider the load time is reduced to ~ 6 seconds and the decimals are parsed correctly. I'm leaving this open in case anyone can give an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting `CacheRows=false` to avoid eagerly loading all the data?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852191/csvprovider-throws-outofmemoryexception

Comment: I actually want to load all the data. Besides, that can't be the problem. Deedle loads all the data and does a lot more (organizing it in Series, etc) than CsvProvider.

Comment: I realize you like to use the type provider but what if you test using `CsvFile` in `FSharp.Data`. Does it have poor or acceptable performance as well? I tried consume 700,000 lines with that and that was ok.

Comment: @FuleSnabel as I write in the question, CsvFile.Load has very good performance. It comes however at the cost of everything being parsed as a string and having to do the transformations to DateTime, int64, etc myself. Deedle on the other hand seems to have excellent performance but its API is more complicated than what I need :-). Since it does way more than CsvProvider, I wonder how the latter's performance can be explained and if it maybe can be tuned.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at the FSharp.Data code. I have to run out the door or I'll be late to an appointment, but it looks to me like the FSharp.Data internal API passes culture strings around, only creating a culture *object* very late in the process -- i.e., FSharp.Data's `TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime` function takes two arguments, `cultureStr` and `text`. That means that the CsvProvider was creating 678,552 `CultureInfo` objects for your CSV file! Obviously this is incredibly inefficient, and FSharp.Data should memoize the returned `CultureInfo` objects.

Comment: I believe I've figured out the cause, and I've opened [a new issue](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/1032) on the FSharp.Data bug tracker to track the problem and a possible solution. You can read all about it there.

Comment: @rmunn great, I'll be happy to provide a synthetic sample of data causing this if anyone needs it though, I don't think the structure of the data is the problem here.

Comment: @kliron FYI: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/1033

Comment: Thanks for all the help, case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by CsvProvider not memoizing the explicitly set `Culture`. The problem was addressed by [this](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/pull/1033) pull request.

Answer (score 6):

I am trying to reproduce the problem you are seeing, since you can't share the data I tried generating some test data. However, on my machine (.NET 4.6.2 F#4.1) I don't see it taking minutes, it takes seconds.

Perhaps you can try to see how my sample application performs in your setup and we can work from that?

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.IO

let clock =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () ->
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let time a =
  let before  = clock ()
  let v       = a ()
  let after   = clock ()
  after - before, v

let generateDataSet () =
  let random            = Random 19740531

  let firstDate         = DateTime(1970, 1, 1)

  let randomInt     ()  = random.Next () |> int64 |> (+) 10000000000L |> string
  let randomDate    ()  = (firstDate + (random.Next () |> float |> TimeSpan.FromSeconds)).ToString("s")
  let randomString  ()  = 
    let inline valid ch =
      match ch with
      | '"'
      | '\\'  -> ' '
      | _     -> ch
    let c   = random.Next () % 16
    let g i =
      if i = 0 || i = c + 1 then '"'
      else 32 + random.Next() % (127 - 32) |> char |> valid
    Array.init (c + 2) g |> String

  let columns =
    [|
      "Id"          , randomInt
      "ForeignId"   , randomInt
      "BirthDate"   , randomDate
      "OtherDate"   , randomDate
      "FirstName"   , randomString
      "LastName"    , randomString
    |]

  use sw      = new StreamWriter ("perf.csv")
  let headers = columns |> Array.map fst |> String.concat ";"
  sw.WriteLine headers
  for i = 0 to 700000 do
    let values = columns |> Array.map (fun (_, f) -> f ()) |> String.concat ";"
    sw.WriteLine values

open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let sample = """Id;ForeignId;BirthDate;OtherDate;FirstName;LastName
11795679844;10287417237;2028-09-14T20:33:17;1993-07-21T17:03:25;",xS@ %aY)N*})Z";"ZP~;"
11127366946;11466785219;2028-02-22T08:39:57;2026-01-24T05:07:53;"H-/QA(";"g8}J?k~"
"""

type PerfFile = CsvProvider<sample, ";">

let readDataWithTp () =
  use streamReader  = new StreamReader ("perf.csv")
  let csvFile       = PerfFile.Load streamReader
  let length        = csvFile.Rows |> Seq.length
  printfn "%A" length

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  Environment.CurrentDirectory <- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

  printfn "Generating dataset..."
  let ms, _ = time generateDataSet
  printfn "  took %d ms" ms

  printfn "Reading dataset..."
  let ms, _ = time readDataWithTp
  printfn "  took %d ms" ms

  0
```

The performance numbers (.NET462 on my desktop):

```
Generating dataset...
  took 2162 ms
Reading dataset...
  took 6156 ms
```

The performance numbers (Mono 4.6.2 on my Macbook Pro):

```
Generating dataset...
  took 4432 ms
Reading dataset...
  took 8304 ms
```

**Update**

It turns out that specifying `Culture` to CsvProvider explicitly seems to degrade performance alot. It can be any culture, not just `sv-SE` but why?

If one checks the code the provider generates for the fast and the slow cases one notice a difference:

**Fast**

```
internal sealed class csvFile@78
{
  internal System.Tuple<long, long, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, string, string> Invoke(object arg1, string[] arg2)
  {
    Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<string> fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[0]);
    long arg_C9_0 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<long>("Id", TextRuntime.ConvertInteger64("", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[1]);
    long arg_C9_1 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<long>("ForeignId", TextRuntime.ConvertInteger64("", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[2]);
    System.DateTime arg_C9_2 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<System.DateTime>("BirthDate", TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[3]);
    System.DateTime arg_C9_3 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<System.DateTime>("OtherDate", TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[4]);
    string arg_C9_4 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>("FirstName", TextRuntime.ConvertString(fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[5]);
    return new System.Tuple<long, long, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, string, string>(arg_C9_0, arg_C9_1, arg_C9_2, arg_C9_3, arg_C9_4, TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>("LastName", TextRuntime.ConvertString(fSharpOption), fSharpOption));
  }
}
```

**Slow**

```
internal sealed class csvFile@78
{
  internal System.Tuple<long, long, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, string, string> Invoke(object arg1, string[] arg2)
  {
    Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<string> fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[0]);
    long arg_C9_0 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<long>("Id", TextRuntime.ConvertInteger64("sv-SE", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[1]);
    long arg_C9_1 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<long>("ForeignId", TextRuntime.ConvertInteger64("sv-SE", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[2]);
    System.DateTime arg_C9_2 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<System.DateTime>("BirthDate", TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("sv-SE", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[3]);
    System.DateTime arg_C9_3 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<System.DateTime>("OtherDate", TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("sv-SE", fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[4]);
    string arg_C9_4 = TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>("FirstName", TextRuntime.ConvertString(fSharpOption), fSharpOption);
    fSharpOption = TextConversions.AsString(arg2[5]);
    return new System.Tuple<long, long, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, string, string>(arg_C9_0, arg_C9_1, arg_C9_2, arg_C9_3, arg_C9_4, TextRuntime.GetNonOptionalValue<string>("LastName", TextRuntime.ConvertString(fSharpOption), fSharpOption));
  }
}
```

More specific this is the difference:

```
// Fast
TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("", fSharpOption), fSharpOption)
// Slow
TextRuntime.ConvertDateTime("sv-SE", fSharpOption), fSharpOption)
```

When we specify a culture this is passed to `ConvertDateTime` which forwards it to `GetCulture`

```
static member GetCulture(cultureStr) =
  if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace cultureStr 
  then CultureInfo.InvariantCulture 
  else CultureInfo cultureStr
```

This means that for the default case we use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but for any other case for each field and row we are creating a `CultureInfo` object. Caching could be done but it's not. The creation process itself doesn't seem to take too much time but something happens when we are parsing with a new `CultureInfo` object each time.

Parsing `DateTime` in `FSharp.Data` essentially is this

```
let dateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces ||| DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind
match DateTime.TryParse(text, cultureInfo, dateTimeStyles) with
```

So let's make a performance test where we use a cached `CultureInfo` object and another one where we create one each time.

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Globalization

let clock =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () ->
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let time a =
  let before  = clock ()
  let v       = a ()
  let after   = clock ()
  after - before, v

let perfTest c cf () =
  let dateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces ||| DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind
  let text = DateTime.Now.ToString ("", cf ())
  for i = 1 to c do
    let culture = cf ()
    DateTime.TryParse(text, culture, dateTimeStyles) |> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  Environment.CurrentDirectory <- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

  let ct    = "sv-SE"
  let cct   = CultureInfo ct
  let count = 10000

  printfn "Using cached CultureInfo object..."
  let ms, _ = time (perfTest count (fun () -> cct))
  printfn "  took %d ms" ms

  printfn "Using fresh CultureInfo object..."
  let ms, _ = time (perfTest count (fun () -> CultureInfo ct))
  printfn "  took %d ms" ms

  0
```

Performance numbers on .NET 4.6.2 F#4.1:

```
Using cached CultureInfo object...
  took 16 ms
Using fresh CultureInfo object...
  took 5328 ms
```

So it seems caching the `CultureInfo` object in `FSharp.Data` should improve `CsvProvider` performance significantly when culture is specified.

Comment: Thanks. I get these results: Generate: 3767 ms, Read: 3764 ms. Definitely not minutes. Now I am even more confused... The only obvious differences with your synthetic data is that I use pipe character as separator and swedish culture. I'll update my question with the actual code.

Comment: @kliron it seems like the next thing to do would be for you to generate some synthetic data which reproduces the problem which you can share.

Comment: @mydogisbox I updated my question. Culture argument seems to be the cause of this. For the record, if I set Culture to "sv_SE" with FuleSnabel's dataset it takes several minutes to load the set.

Comment: Culture can certainly cause problems. I had a application hang once due to sami culture caused string comparison to be very slow. I can check with sv_SE culture as well.

Comment: Hmm I try this `type PerfFile = CsvProvider<sample, ";", Culture="sv-SE">` and that doesn't cause it to degrade performance neither on .NET 4.6.2 or Mono 4.6.2. Do you mind posting an example that cause it to degrade for you? I have the source to `FSharp.Data` and is pretty used to profiling it so I thought I could check it for you.

Comment: That reproduction code calls `generateDataSet` twice in the `main` function. Surely you meant to call `readDataWithTp` the second time? When I make that change, I get 5084 ms to generate the data, and 8637 ms to read it with the default culture. A second run with explicitly specifying `en-US` as the culture took 4962 ms to generate the data, and 395817 ms (about six and a half minutes) to read the data. So your reproduction does reproduce the problem, once the right function is actually called.

Comment: @FuleSnabel strange that it doesn't happen in your case. The data is almost definitely not the problem, I get the exact same behavior when I load your perf data. It takes almost 6 minutes to complete with explicitly set Culture and 3 seconds without.

Comment: As @rmunn pointed out I had a problem with the code. That should be fixed now.